# Is there a way to send notifications in the background app automatically in firebase console without typing the necessary inputs?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am unable to send notifications automatically on the background of my app using firebase cloud messaging i dont know if my project needs an admin or web server to make it happen because it only consist of machine and an app that communicates through esp8266 while my app is for viewing and monitoring only.

I tried several ways on fcm but all of those process requires manual input for the notification to be sent, what I need is to send a notification automatically when there are data changes in firebase real-time database. I don't know if i need to do it programmatically in android studio or activate something in firebase cloud messaging.